# Issue giving image parameter for local report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I was trying to add an image parameter for rdlc which run inside vb project.
I was giving external image parameter as like this:

> ```
>     report.EnableExternalImages = True
>     Dim param As ReportParameter = New ReportParameter("ImgPath", "C:\sample.jpg")
>     report.SetParameters(param)
>     report.Refresh()
> ```

Where ImgPath is my Parameter name which I addeded in RDLC and C:\Sample.jpg is where my image is located. 
Something is wrong in giving image parameter and image path. I am getting report printing error just when I added the image inside my rdlc. It could print well without the image.
Where have I done wrong?
And what about forward slashes and backward slashes do affect? I saw different uses in different places of suggested solutions that I found.
(P.S I am not using report viewer inside my project)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved.
I have to include **"file:///"** when giving value of the image. 
Which must be

> ="file:///" & Parameters!ImgPath.Value

It is a very simple thing indeed, only that I haven't known exactly which is supposed to be used.

And inside you code behind, just give the file path normally. **"C:/.../image.png"**

> report.EnableExternalImages = True
>           Dim param As ReportParameter = New ReportParameter("ImgPath", "C:/.../image.png")
>           report.SetParameters(param)
>           report.Refresh()